# SSL in java - no RSA?

Tags: java, ssl

```
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keyStore.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("keystore.jks"), "haslo1".toCharArray());
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory =
    TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX", "SunJSSE");
    trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
    X509TrustManager x509TrustManager = null;
    for (TrustManager trustManager : trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers()) {
    if (trustManager instanceof X509TrustManager) {
    x509TrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManager;
    break;
    }
    }
        if (x509TrustManager == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

      sslContext.init( KeyManagerFactory.getInstance( "RSA" ).getKeyManagers(),
       new TrustManager[]{x509TrustManager}, null);
```

I've got this code but on line of sslContext.init I get following exception:
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA KeyManagerFactory not available

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `KeyManagerFactory` algorithms have nothing to do with `RSA`. What can be used is documented in the [Sun JSSE provider documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider) (or the documentation of the provider, if you're using a different one).

The only available options here are `SunX509` and `PKIX`. Generally speaking, it's better to use `KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()`. You can also do this for the `TrustManagerFactory`, instead of hard-coding `PKIX`. (The default values for the Sun JRE are listed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization).)

Comment: I get java.lang.IllegalStateException: KeyManagerFactoryImpl is not initialized

Comment: Sure, you can't just call `getKeyManagers()` on it either, you need to call `init` first.

Answer (score 5):

Replace

```
KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("RSA")
```

with

```
KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
```

Comment: I get java.lang.IllegalStateException: KeyManagerFactoryImpl is not initialized